# trying to make object of class and then to display.setCurrent(Class) but not working

Tags: java, canvas, java-me

I am trying to make a new object from `StartGame` and show in the `GameMidlet` class, but whenever I click on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button to display the content of `StartGame`, the screen doesn't show anything, instead showing just the same `GameMidlet` menu. Please help me find where the bug is. Thank you in advance.

```
public class GameMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener, ItemCommandListener  {

GameCanvas gameCanvasNew;
Display display;

StartGame startGame;

Command restartCommand;
Vector mGameCanvasList;
GameCanvas gameCanvasSecond;

private Form formMenu;

private Command exitCommand;
private Command okCommand;
private Command exitCommandGame;

private StringItem menuItem;
private StringItem siNewGameItem;
private StringItem siResume;
private StringItem siExit;

public void startApp() {

    formMenu = new Form("Start Menu", new Item[] {getNewGameItem(), getResumeItem(), getExitItem()});
    display  = Display.getDisplay(this);


    display.setCurrent(formMenu);


}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {


    }


public StringItem getNewGameItem(){

    if(siNewGameItem == null){
        siNewGameItem = new StringItem("New Game","", Item.BUTTON);
        siNewGameItem.addCommand(getOkCommand());
        siNewGameItem.setItemCommandListener(this);
    }

    return siNewGameItem;

}

public StringItem getResumeItem(){

    if(siResume == null){
        siResume = new StringItem("Resume", "", Item.BUTTON);
        siResume.addCommand(getOkCommand());
        siResume.setItemCommandListener(this);
    }

    return siResume;
}

public StringItem getExitItem(){

    if(siExit == null){
        siExit = new StringItem("Exit","",Item.BUTTON);
        siExit.addCommand(getExitCommand());
        siExit.setItemCommandListener(this);
    }

    return siExit;
}

public Command getOkCommand(){

    if(okCommand == null){

        okCommand = new Command("OK", Command.OK, 0);
    }

    return okCommand;

}

public Command getExitCommand(){

    if(exitCommand == null){
        exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
    }
    return exitCommand;
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Item item) {

    if(item == siExit){
        if(c == exitCommand){
            destroyApp(true);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
    }

    else if(item == siNewGameItem){
            if(c == okCommand){ 
                // i am having problem at here......
                startGame = new StartGame();

                display.setCurrent(startGame);
                startGame.startGameNew();

            }
        }


    }
}
```

**StartGame.java**

```
public class StartGame extends Canvas implements CommandListener {

GameCanvas game;
Display display;
Command exitCommand;
Command restartCommand;
Vector mGameCanvasList;
GameCanvas fistList;


public void startGameNew() {


    game = new GameCanvas();


    exitCommand     = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
    restartCommand  = new Command("Restart", Command.OK, 0);

    game.addCommand(exitCommand);
    game.addCommand(restartCommand);

    game.setCommandListener(this);
    game.setCommandListener(this);
    game.startThread();

}


protected void paint(Graphics g) {

}
}
```